# how to write algorithm in latex?

Tags: algorithms

I want to write this algorithm:

```
for(i=0;i<nbOfPedCurr;i++){
 for(j=0;j<nbOfPedPrev;j++){
    int idCurr=idCurrentFrame;
    int idPrev=idPrevFrame;
    if(idCurr==idPrev){
         CurrObj=extract(CurrMask,CurrPos);
         PrevObj=extract(PrevFrame,PrevPos);
         xor(CurrObj,PrevObj,dest);
         Sum=Sum+dest;
    }
   }
  }
```

Can any one help me to write it?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what programming language you are using but you could look at the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. This will allow you to typeset programming code.

So you can do something that looks like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C++}          % Set your language (you can change the language for each code-block optionally)
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]  % Start your code-block
for(i=0;i<nbOfPedCurr;i++){
    for(j=0;j<nbOfPedPrev;j++){
        int idCurr=idCurrentFrame;
        int idPrev=idPrevFrame;
        if(idCurr==idPrev){
            CurrObj=extract(CurrMask,CurrPos);
            PrevObj=extract(PrevFrame,PrevPos);
            xor(CurrObj,PrevObj,dest);
            Sum=Sum+dest;
        }
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

And that should help with typesetting and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Can I add a caption to this algorithm?

Comment: @para `\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption={whatever}]`